# Up one's ass vs. In one's ass

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, offensive-language

Why is *stick/shove/etc **up** one's ass* much more common than ***in/into*** one's ass?

Comment: People keep using this word, *why*... And I keep asking back, why do you not use *blagoveshchensk* to mean "car"? Answer me that question, and you'll have answered yours.

Comment: That reminds me of Frindle...

Comment: Probably because when you tell someone to shove it, they're in a position where _in_ is _up_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is a more aggressive description of the act being used as a metaphor.  Well, mostly as a metaphor.  One would never say the nurse "stuck a 250mg acetaminophen suppository up . . . ," rather one would say that the nurse "inserted a suppository into my. . . ."  The more aggressive makes a stronger metaphor.

Comment: So basically "up" here kinda means "far in"?

Comment: No it doesn't mean 'far in' at all. It's simply a phrase that adds rudeness to 'arse'.

Comment: Why is "up" more rude than "in"? Don't ask me about blagoveshchensk though :)

Comment: _Up_ is not more rude; it's more aggressive. _In_ suggests a gentler treatment. You _put_ something _in_; you _shove_ something _up_.

Answer (score 0):

One part of the answer may be that *ass*, or *arse*, has got two different meanings.

*Ass*, or *arse*, has the same meaning as *buttocks* or *bottom*, as in:
"The nurse said, 'Right then.  Don't just sit on your *arse*!' No sooner had I got up than, without so much as a Howdydoody, she'd stuck the needle in my *arse*."

The prepositions *on/in* are used because here *ass* or *arse* refers a solid object.

However, *arse* is sometimes used to replace the more technically correct *arsehole* (a three-dimensional space).
"Then, to make matters worse, she'd stuck a suppository right up my **arse/arsehole*!  When I told her that she had promised it wouldn't hurt, she just replied, "Well, I guess I was just talking out of my **arse/arsehole*."

I don't know what it would be like to have a suppository shoved in my *arse* (solid object), but I'd rather not find out.

Comment: How did a perfectly reasonable discussion of up, in or into a rectum descend into a discussion of arse and ass?

Comment: Look again.  I think the word in the question was ass, not rectum.

Comment: Well, yes, in a literal sense you are correct. It was ass, not arse and not rectum. I was commenting on your unnecessary complication of adding arse to the discussion.  Anatomically, the specific site under discussion is, in fact, the rectum, a space rather than a structure.